# Gridview row width shrinking when a control is not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the code below. I am trying to get the gridview row width to stay permanent and not shrink when a control invisible.  When a control is visible, the row looks fine, when it is invisible, the row combines with the next row in the gridview. Any ideas?

```
if (File.Exists(@"\\10.10.1.45\public\hdma\" + NDCNumber + ".pdf"))
{
    e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = true;
    HDMALink.NavigateUrl = @"\\10.10.1.45\public\hdma\" + NDCNumber + ".pdf";
}
else
{
    e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false;
}
```

html

```
<Columns>
    <asp:HyperLinkField Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFields="NDCNumber" Text="D" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign ="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="1%" ItemStyle-ForeColor="#284775" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="None" />
    <asp:HyperLinkField Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFields="NDCNumber" HeaderText="Print" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Text="S" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="6%" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="None" />
    <asp:HyperLinkField Target="_blank" HeaderText="HDMA" Text="H" ItemStyle-Width="1%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-ForeColor="#284775" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="NDCNumber" HeaderText="NDC Number" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign ="Center" ItemStyle-Width="12%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" /> 
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign ="Center"  ItemStyle-Width="35%" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="None"  />                        
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Strength" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Strength" ItemStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="None" />
    <pac:BoundButtonField CommandName="Edit" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" NavigateUrl="~/general.aspx" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="None" />
    <pac:BoundButtonField  CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="5%"  ConfirmMsg = "Are you sure you wish to delete this product?" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="None" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set widths using absolute values instead of percentages.

```
ItemStyle-Width="60px"
```